# #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, wamp, phpmyadmin

I have this error when trying to connect to my phpmyadmin. I tried all the solutions but nothing works. 
I changed password in config.inc and cleared cookies, restarted services of wamp but nothing.
Changed phpmyadmin.conf accesses as well but still nothing.

Does anyone have any advice or someone that experienced the same problem that could help.

Comment: Did you try removing phpmyadmin and install fresh?

Comment: If you have "tried all the solutions" then there is no solution we can offer that would work.
Seriously though, can you log into MySQL from the command line? `mysql --user=root --password=<PASSWORD>`?

Comment: @hagubear. Yes but still does not work

Comment: @LN1 : What is your operating system, wamp version?

Comment: Found the solution, updated mysql and everything works fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is 5 years old and the original poster states in the comments: “[Found the solution, updated mysql and everything works fine](https://superuser.com/questions/832645/1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes#comment1093976_832645).”

Answer (score 0):

When making a root ssh connection, `~/.ssh/conf` has to have the uncommented line `allow root-login=yes` probably isn't a good analogue for what is happening here as I have no experience with WAMP but it might help/